# What is the genral form of the laurent exspansion of $\frac{1}{(z-\alpha)^n}$

Tags: summation, laurent-series, geometric-series

This is a question from a text book (Saff and Snider, Complex analysis for matemetics science and engineering).

> Obtain the general formula for the laurent expansion of
>   $$ f_n(z) = \frac{1}{(z-\alpha)^n}$$ $$(n = 1,2,...)$$
>   that is valid for $|z| > |\alpha|$

I have been scratching arround with geometric series and the formula
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b^n = \frac{1}{1-b}$$ where $|b|<1$
but I can't seem to make progress. Acording to the solutions the answer is;

> $$\sum_{j=n}^\infty \alpha^{j-n} \frac{(j-1)!}{(j-n)!(n-1)!} z^{-j}$$

(Also is this actualy difficult or am I just an idiot?)

Comment: Never consider yourself an idiot. Sometimes, the answers to the easiest of the questions in maths elude us while we easily solve much tougher problems....

Comment: If you can't find an easier way, here's an idea: first [compute the coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Power_series_raised_to_powers) of the formal power series $F(X) = \left(\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} X^k\right)^n = \frac{1}{(1-X)^n}$, then consider $\frac{1}{(z-\alpha)^n}$ as $z^{-n} (1 - \frac{\alpha}{z})^{-n} = z^{-n} F(\frac{\alpha}{z})$.

Comment: After user237444, the fact that sometime you could not understand does not imply in any manner that you are an idiot. What it could mean is that the person who teached you the topic did not make it in the appropriate manner at least for you. I am not a teacher but, as long as you would not understand, I shall feel responsible of the failure because I did not find the proper way to present it to you (which would could work with somebody else). All of us are different and each of us reacts in a different manner. So, from now, I **forbid** you to think, tell, write or dream that you are an idiot.

Comment: See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).